# Clean core data when updating app to App Store

Tags: objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

I have been using lightweight migration for updating data model. I want to make a release where I clean the data base and do not migrate the data. What is the best way to do that? Has anybody did this whit a App Store release?

UPDATE

```
NSDictionary *options = @{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: @NO,
                         NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: @NO};

NSError *error = nil;
__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {

    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kCleanDB]) {
        NSLog(@"Deleting sql database, due to unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:storeURL.path error:&error];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:kCleanDB];
    }

    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is delete your persistent store on startup, before you create a managed object context.

If you're using Apple's standard pattern to create the Core Data stack, when you access the MOC it'll create a new, empty store.

You'll need to track whether you've done this "upgrade". To do that just store a flag in `NSUserDefaults` once it's done, and check each time to make sure you only do it once.

Comment: And for the love of whatever you hold holy, __do not delete user data__ make sure that it is only data provided by your app that you delete.

Comment: How about deleting the DB it seems to work, and I've change the flags to not migrate the data from one data model to the next